# How to move Plank dock vertically

Tags: dock, plank

I want to know if it's possible, by modifying some configuration files, to change the vertical position of Plank dock. Unfortunately in the settings you can only decide whether to put it at the top, bottom, left or right while I would like to keep it at the bottom but slightly higher than where it is put by default.

Screenshot
[image: -]

As you can see from the screen, the lower edge of the dock is too attached to the lower edge of the screen, I would like to move it slightly higher.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the theme, not the settings. So in `/usr/share/plank/theme/<themename>/dock.theme` you' ll find two entries:

```
#The padding on the bottom dock edge, in tenths of a percent of IconSize.
BottomPadding=2.5
#The padding between items on the dock, in tenths of a percent of IconSize.
ItemPadding=2
```

Change the padding until it fits your needs

Comment: I've tried that, but what it does is to extend the border between the icons and the bottom part of the dock (as you can see in the screen). What I want to do is to move the entire dock a bit higher. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flCp2.jpg)

Comment: Not possible. One of the reasons why plank to so fast. Use cairo-dock. It is much more configurable. BTW- that is no answer but a comment. [Read here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19074/when-should-i-answer-and-when-should-i-comment)